# return type in C#

Tags: c#

I have two classes named **ROAD** and **PATH**

```
public class ROAD
{
    public string getData()
    {
      return "Marlton Road";
    }
}

public class PATH
{
    public string getData()
    {
        return "Tagore Path";
    }
 }
```

Also i have a function named FETCH() in my Static Void Main

FETCH() contains following code

```
public returnType FETCH(bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
       ROAD obj=new ROAD();
       return obj;
    }
    else
    {
       PATH obj=new PATH();
       return obj;
    }
}
```

Now my question is what should be the return type of function FETCH().
Or is there any other way to implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using interface would be the best way:

```
public interface IData
{
    string getData();
}

public class ROAD : IData
{
    public string getData()
    {
        return "Marlton Road";
    }
}

public class PATH : IData
{
    public string getData()
    {
        return "Tagore Path";
    }
}

public IData FETCH(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        ROAD obj = new ROAD();
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {
        PATH obj = new PATH();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It would have to be `object` in this case, as `PATH` and `ROAD` have no common base type. (They also don't follow .NET naming conventions - something which should be fixed, along with your `getData` method, and your `FETCH` method. Even in sample code, it's worth trying to make your names follow the normal conventions).

Consider making the two classes implement an interface or give them a common base class. That common type could then be the return type of the method. It looks like you could probably have an interface with your `getData` method in, for example. Hopefully in your real classes it could have a more meaningful name - something to do with both paths and roads.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create an interface that both PATH and ROAD implement (e.g. IGetData) then have both classes implement it, and have FETCH return an IGetData.

Answer (score 2):

`Object`, and then you cast to `ROAD` or `PATH`.  Or, if they share a common base class, return that.  [See also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

But you probably don't want to do this.  ROAD and PATH should each have their own static factory method:

```
class ROAD {
  static ROAD newRoad() { return new ROAD(); }
}

class PATH {
  static PATH newPath() { return new PATH(); }
}
```

Or some other, better pattern, depending on why you're doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
interface IWithData
{
    string GetData();
}

class Path: IWithData
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Tagore Path";
    }
}

class Road: IWithData
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Marlton Road";
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    // ...
    public IWithData FETCH(bool flag)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            Road obj=new Road();
            return obj;
        }
        else
        {
            Path obj=new Path();
            return obj;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's `object`. If you want it to be something else, you just have to have those classes share a common base or implement a common interface.  For example:

```
public class Road : IPavedSurface
{     
    // members
}
public class Path : IPavedSurface
{     
    // members
}

// then 
public IPavedSurface Fetch(bool flag)     
{
```